# "Done with the task" or "Done with task"?

Tags: definite-articles

Which is the correct form:

"[are you] Done with the task?" or "[are you] Done with task?"

It feels to me that the first form is the correct one, as it implies the specific task that was assigned earlier on.

Comment: Yes, your impression is correct!

Comment: Your question is more appropriate for [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/). Our associates there will surely provide you with a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done with the task.
I can be done with painting or done with the painting. The first one refers to the general task or occupation of painting. The second refers to a specific painting.
Our house renovation is going well. I'm done with painting (the rooms).  I'm sick of all the criticism my art is getting. I'm done with painting (as a hobby/profession). But in these, painting is a noun form of the verb, to paint.
You can say
I'm done with tasking.
I'm done with tasks.
I'm done with the/a/one task.

You can use a singular noun as the complement of a preposition, but it would be very contrived.
Every tournament let's you choose to complete with sword, lance, or mace.
After 10 years, I'm done with sword, and I'm moving onto lance.